# While div tag refresh using JavaScript is refreshing the whole page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to refresh the div tag using js.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#product_slidebar').on('click', function() {
    console.log("2");
    $('#data').load('{{URL::to("/product") }}');
    alert("m");
  });
});
```

At the alert box execution I can see that the page is loaded in div tag but after clicking <kbd>OK</kbd> on alert box page automatically reloaded the page

[image: console log]

Comment: Is `#product_slidebar` an achor link by any chance?  If so you will want to preventDefault..   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: yes mistakenly i put a blank anchor link in that tag. thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prevent default functionality on the element being clicked

```js
$('#product_slidebar').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("2");
    $('#data').load('{{URL::to("/product") }}');
    alert("m");
  });
```